# How to create extension for KotlinDependencyHandler interface in buildSrc?

Tags: kotlin

I created `buildSrc` module for handling dependencies in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile app. Also, I created the extension for adding dependencies as implementation in an easy way. Here's one of them:

```
fun DependencyHandler.implementation(list: List<String>) {
    list.forEach { dependency ->
        add("implementation", dependency)
    }
}
```

But if I want to use such an extension in the shared module I should create an extension for `KotlinDependencyHandler`. This interface is currently unrecognised in `buildSrc` so how can I add it to `buildSrc` module?

Here's the content of `buildSrc` `build.gradle` file:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add dependencies inside `buildSrc`.
Example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31")
}
```

Don't forget to sync it. Then you can add your extension.

Comment: Can you please make your answer a little more verbose? Where does that dependency block has to be? Inside the build.gradle.kts it's not referencable from other (sub)projects.